What is the best epoch to evaluate the test images?
I created a training, a validation and a test set for an image classification task. Then, I did training using the training and did evaluation on validation set. So, the next step is to evaluate the test set, basically it is for inference. To select the best epoch model, I normally check the validation loss. However, I'm not sure if this way is correct. I add the results as a picture and I marked the best train/val accuracy and the lowest train/val loss. The loss function is the cross entropy.

The later steps are clearly overfitting, but still the training loss gets lower and lower till the 25th epoch. If I would only check the val loss, I might select the 13th epoch. Or the highest validation accuracy could also be important.
I read some articles or forum questions like this, this, and this, and several others, but there is no real conclusion on this topic. So is there a general solution for this kind of situations, or should I consider every classification/object detection task differently and decide accordingly?

Just a FYI, you get the minimum validation loss already at epoch 4.

Surrogate losses are used precisely because measures like accuracy are flawed. You want to use a score that is minimized when the predicted class probabilities match the true class probabilities (i.e., a proper scoring rule).
Cross-entropy is very closely related to the logarithmic score, which is a strictly proper scoring rule. Accuracy is an improper scoring rule, meaning the accuracy can in principle increase while moving away from the true class probabilities.
Hence, you should go with the lowest validation loss.
(The training loss is not valid for selecting the best epoch, because it can go down due to overfitting.)

thank you for the reply, it is very helpful as well as the links that you have provided. but what about the validation accuracy, should I think all accuracies as improper or validation accuracy might still give some idea about the quality of the result?

The issues with accuracy hold for both training and validation. You can still include it if you like, but also include the loss function and base your decisions on that.

got it, thanks!
